# Conference name in the title page of the presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am wondering how to insert the name of the conference in the title of my presentation immediately after the date?

I'll highly appreciate your help! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193979/254447 You can DIY the title page instead of using \maketitle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the date is the last element of your title page, you could simply add the conference name after it. If this creates too much spacing between the date and the conference name, you could manually tweak it a bit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{text}
\author{names}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  
  \vskip-1.5cm
  
  \centering
  Conference name
  
  \vskip1.5cm
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But in your template I do not see University?

Comment: @ZFR I did not set an `\institute`, which is presumably what you used to add an university.

Comment: Great! It helped me actually! +1

Answer (score 2):

On top of my comment, you can also use

```
\titlegraphic{XX conference}
```